# TortoiseHG not updating shell icons after commit/push

Tags: shell, icons, mercurial, source-code, tortoise-hg

My team uses MercurialHG/TortoiseHG for code management (historical thing), and all used to work well. With the recent updates to either Tortoise (6+), or possibly Windows 10, I've had the issue that the icons on the folders do not seem to update to show that the code beneath has been updated...

[image: Screen shot of affected folder]

The code in the folders beneath those marked (!) are fully committed and code pushed to the repo.

I've tried recommitting, repushing, pulling and synchronising, several times, but to no avail.

Am I missing something (...except for GIT)?

Comment: Do any of the answers in [git - TortoiseGit modified sign (icon overlay) is not updating - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137929/tortoisegit-modified-sign-icon-overlay-is-not-updating) help you?

Comment: @DavidPostill - No, I've been through all of that now. Thanks for pointing it out, mind - I do appreciate it. I've even tried repulling the repo and that turned all of the icons red... It's not that important - I know that the files are up to date in the repo. I'll keep looking and see if anything shows up.

Comment: I've occasionally had this issue and pressing F5 in explorer to refresh the view usually works.

Comment: @StayOnTarget - Yes, that was one of the first things I tried. Thanks for your help. It seems that this is actually some kind of inherent bug with Tortoise that was never fixed when it was first discovered, years ago.